# Facebook is not picking my webpage logo when shared

Tags: php, html, facebook, image, facebook-sharer

I am using following information in head section:

```
<head>

  <meta property="og:title" content="Title" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="This is description" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image/logo/logo.gif" /> 

</head>
```

Facebook is picking title and description but not getting image. When I use image URL directly in browser then it shows it on new page. It means image path is correct.

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the Facebook Debugger, it might tell you what is wrong:
    https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I used this debug tool and it is showing logo in that tool perfectly. I don't know why it is not shown on facebook page ?????

Comment: can you let us know the page URL?

Answer (score 0):

Recrawl your page with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Incase if you ahd shared in past any otehr image, facebook caches it. Once you revalidate facebook destroys cache and use new settings. Incase if anything is wron with image height width, facebook debug tool will tell.